# How to extract Facebook posts information

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this code to read the last post with location of all my facebook friends:
(FacebookFriend is an object I've created mySelf and contains also the friend's id and _facebookFriends contains all my facebook friends)

```
_postsWithLocationList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (FacebookFriend *currentFriend in _facebookFriends) {

    FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/posts?limit=1&with=location",currentFriend.id];
    FBRequest *postsWithLocationRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:path parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [connection addRequest:postsWithLocationRequest completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *postData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
        if (postData.count != 0) //some people don't have any post with position
        {
              // how to extract "place" object?
        }
    }];
    [connection start];
}
```

and then I would like to store every location in my NSMutable array _postsWithLocationList.
Once I've extracted *postData I printed it's content and it looked like a dictionary (where "place" is a key) exactly as in the Facebook Graph API Explorer. 
But when I printed

```
NSLog(@"%i", postData.count);
```

I saw that the length of "postData" was always 1, so I think that it's a single object that contains all the instances of the post. I looked at https://developers.facebook.com but I don't understand the type of this object and how to extract it's content.

Comment: "How to parse Facebook posts objects using Xcode" - in no way. Xcode can't parse Facebook's response format. You may want to do it **using your own application** instead.

Comment: So what can I do if I want to develop an application that also reads Facebook posts location if Xcode cannot parse a post object?

Comment: See, the problem is terminology. It's not Xcode that parses the response. Do you think it's the IDE that does so? What if you used Eclipse for development? Or `vi`? It's **your code, your application** that parses the response. And you write code for achieving that.

Comment: I've badly expressed my trouble. Is my question more clear now? (I've just edited it). In the application I'm developing I make a lot of Facebook Graph API queries which return me a dictionary (for example I ask for user's friend list and facebook returns me an array of "id" and "name") and it's easy to extract the information I need. But in this case the situation is different because the "data" object in a post is not a dictionary. So I'd like to understand if there is a easy way to extract information from this "data" object as I did for all my previous queries

Comment: Perfect. Well, what is the class of the object it returns? It alll depends on that.

Comment: This is the core of my trouble. I'm looking for that but I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: You can find its class by logging `NSLog(@"%@", theObject.class);`. What does that print?

Comment: "data" is a FBGraphObjectArray, so I've extracted the "place" using [data dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"place"]] and finally I have a dictionary with all the place properties. Unfortunately when I print NSLog(@"%@", place.class); it writes __NSDictionaryI, and there is no interface of this type of dictionary in the Xcode guide..

Comment: Oh, is that only the problem? `NSDictionary` is a class cluster (google what those are), and `__NSDictionaryI` is one of its concrete subclasses. It's just a normal `NSDictionary`. Go ahead and use `objectForKey:` as you would use it otherwise.